# Exception in DevExpress 14.1 ASPxHttpHandlerModule

Tags: asp.net, web-config, devexpress

I am new to DevExpress and have some troubles getting an ASP.NET Web Form to work on our server. The error that I am getting is:

> [ Exception: To work properly, DevExpress components require ASPxHttpHandlerModule registered in the web.config file. For details, see: http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument7540 ]
>
> DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControl.AssertModuleRegistration() +376 DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxDataWebControlBase.OnInit(EventArgs e) +20 System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +186 System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +421 System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +421  System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2098

I have set up the ASPxHttpHandlerModule as in [documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument7540) for IIS 7 (integerated mode) as shown below:

```
    <httpModules>
        <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v14.1, Version=14.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule"/>
    </httpModules>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v14.1, Version=14.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET" path="DX.ashx" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v14.1, Version=14.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule"/>
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
        <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v14.1, Version=14.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET" path="DX.ashx" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

I have a feeling that I have mis-understood something somewhere. For instance what is "DX.ashx"?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the following article for solving your issue :

> https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q587235
>
> https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument7540
>
> http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q529618